# Redirect a URL to Another Domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a thousand URL in my old domain. I want to make a new domain and redirect all url from old domain to new domain.

For example my old domain is `http://www.domain1.web.id/` my new domain is `http://www.domain2.com/`.

And for example url a content from my old domain is `http://www.domain1.web.id/itazurana-kiss-the-movie-propose/` and I want to redirect that content url to my new domain.

so, url will be like this in my new domain `http://www.domain2.com/itazurana-kiss-the-movie-propose/`.

by the way I am using Wordpress.

what I have to do to redirect all my old url to a new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding rewrite rule in your .htaccess file.
Open your .htaccess file and paste the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.web.id$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.web.id$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```